# Select only items for which all of its values for each line_number are null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which resembles the following:

```
| item_number | line_number |  value |
|-------------|-------------|--------|
|           1 |           1 | (null) |
|           1 |           2 |     10 |
|           1 |           3 | (null) |
|           2 |           1 | (null) |
|           2 |           2 | (null) |
|           2 |           3 | (null) |
|           3 |           1 |      5 |
|           3 |           2 | (null) |
|           3 |           3 | (null) |
```

There are three unique items (according to `item_number`), and each item has three `line_number`'s. I would like to return all the items for which the `value` for each `line_number` is null.

For this table, I would return the following:

```
| item_number |
|-------------|
|           2 |
```

, since only `item_number = 2` has all of it's `line_number`'s `value IS NULL`.

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_A (
  item_number INT,
  line_number INT,
  value       INT,
);

INSERT INTO tbl_A VALUES (1, 1, NULL), (1, 2, 10), (1, 3, NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl_A VALUES (2, 1, NULL), (2, 2, NULL), (2, 3, NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl_A VALUES (3, 1, 5), (3, 2, NULL), (3, 3, NULL);

CREATE TABLE tbl_B (
  item_number INT
);

INSERT INTO tbl_B VALUES (2);
```

Comment: This doesn't require a pivot or an unpivot so I'm not sure why they're tagged. Just a select distinct with a not exists or left self-join or count(case...).

Comment: @ZLK I've removed those tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT  item_number
FROM    tbl_A
GROUP BY item_number
HAVING  COUNT(value) = 0
```

Comment: Suppose that instead of `NULL`, we have empty strings? i.e. `''`. I was thinking something like:

`HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(value, '')) = 0`

Comment: You could do, but in your DDL, that column is defined as an INT.

Answer (score 1):

Using `not exists`:

```
select distinct item_number
from tbl_A
where not exists (select 1 from tbl_A a
                  where a.item_number = tbl_A.item_number
                  and value is not null)
```

Using `not in`:

```
select distinct item_number
from tbl_A
where item_number not in (select distinct item_Number
                       from tbl_A where value is not null)
```